# Rails API Create Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

api application that has a create method that looks like:

```
# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: api_v1_post_path(@post)
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

and then I use a curl command like:

`curl --data "name=test" http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/posts`

which creates a post, but without the name = test like it should be. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this out

```
curl --data "post[name]=test" http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/posts
```

Answer (score 0):

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"post": {"name":"test"}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts`